# How to plot specific data In R

Tags: data-science

I have a dataset that consist of road accident cases in a country from 2000,2020. How do I plot a graph that shows total accident cases in a specific year and total number? I only know to print/plot a graph generally by using

plot(Accd$Year, Accd$TotNumber)

The code above is unable to plot specific year data.

Please assist as i am beginner. Below is the head of the data set.

NEGERI `JUMLAH \r\nKML~` JUMLAH \r\nKML~ `JUMLAH \r\nKML~
                                     
1 JOHOR             59501            2011              366
2 JOHOR             62316            2012              378

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a histogram and based on your data set/frame, the function will need some changes.

You can use this one as an idea:

```
hist(d$year,xlab="Year",main="",col = "green",border = "red")
```